# Getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.impute'" despite having latest sklearn installed (0.19.1)

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, anaconda

I am doing a Kaggle competition which requires imputing some missing data. I have installed latest `Anaconda(4.5.4)` with all relevant dependencies (i.e `scikit-learn (0.19.1)`).

When I try to import the modules I am getting the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.impute'

I have tried to import different sklearn modules without any problems. It seems that only sklearn.impute is missing.

Comment: I think `sklearn.impute` may be a version 0.20.1 (dev) thing. 0.19.1 has `sklearn.preprocessing.imputation`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As BallpointBen pointed out, sklearn.impute is not yet released in the latest stable release (0.19.1). Currently it's supported only in 0.20.dev0.

Answer (score 1):

It's a version error. Here's a fix that worked for me while working in Jupyter Notebook. From your Terminal:

conda update anaconda

conda update scikit-learn

- Then restart your jupyter kernal

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
```

Works on both python3.5 and python3.6

(In or Out of jupyter notebook)

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
it works.

Comment: How and why does this work? *[How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)*

Answer (score 0):

Another option is SimpleImputer, it works fine:

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of our environment has sklearn 0.23.1 which includes sklearn.impute.

```
import sklearn 
print (sklearn.__version__)
```

output:

```
0.23.1
```

If the library is not updated you go to Anaconda Prompt and

```
conda update sklearn
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
i=Imputer(missing_values=np.nan,strategy='mean',verbose=0)
```

Answer (score -1):

For sklearn version 23.x, please refer https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/release_highlights/plot_release_highlights_0_23_0.html

There are two ways to use SimpleImputer.
1 imputer.SimpleImputer

```
from sklearn import impute
imputer = impute.SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
```

2 SimpleImputer

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer  
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
```

Comment: Hi Mayur, thanks for trying to help here, and congratulations on your first contribution. However, it looks like you're repeating the steps addressed in the question, rather than providing a solution. It might help to try and reproduce the question, using the version of the specified package, before answering to this forum.